# Creating JWT using an RSA private key from PFX file in Javascript (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, rsa, jwt

I'm trying to create a RSA private key from a PFX file that I would be able to use to create a JWT.
I don't know much about the security side of things, so struggling to find the right library to use.

I have a provided PFX, which I need to use to encrypt a JSON payload (within a Node app) before posting it off to a 3rd party (Java) backend server for decryption.

Any sample code to do this would be much appreciated.